# Topsy, Twitter, Curl, Bash

Tags: bash, curl, twitter, arabic, topsy

The code below does not work for foreign words but works perfectly on english words.

```
let int=1244764800
let start=86400+$int 
let l=86400*7
let end=$int-$l

for (( k = $start ; k > $end ; k=k-3600 )) do
for (( j = 1 ; j < 11 ; j++ )) do
let mintime=$k-3600;
let maxtime=$k
searchwords="سلام"

#echo $maxtime
curl "http://otter.topsy.com/search.json?q="${searchwords}"&page="$j"&perpage=100&mintime="${mintime}"&maxtime="${maxtime}"&apikey=FAF7F2D0D8A143978CB7762CE35FCF99"
done
done
```

This yields the following:

`curl: (7) couldn't connect to host`

```
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

I reiterate that this script works perfectly with ENGLISH words, but I need to run this with foreign words so I would appreciate any help/guidance!
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to `urlencode` any non-ascii characters. 
Try using `curl --data-urlencode`, rather than just `curl`.

If just prepending the URL string won't work, move parameters to data (read up on `-d` of `curl`) and still use `--data-urlencode`

Here's a working example:

```
curl -G --data-urlencode "q=سلام" -d page=1 -d mitime=1244764800 -d maxtime=1245764800 -d apikey=FAF7F2D0D8A143978CB7762CE35FCF99 "http://otter.topsy.com/search.json"
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to url escape the characters of searchwords.

You can try to use `--data-urlencode` argument of curl.

There is a nice writeup [in this link](http://blog.famzah.net/2011/08/25/url-escape-in-bash/) on how to do it in bash using perl or just plain bash.